Некоторые сайты видят мой IP как украинский
Я сам нахожусь в России. Арендовал в Финляндии VDS сервер(Провайдер зарегистрирован в Гонконге). Всё работает, для многих сайтов я в Финляндии, но для некоторых я почему-то в Украине. Кто с этим сталкивался, как это исправить?

Тут скорее связанно с языком. Россия в европейском сегменте забанена, а вот вторая страна с русским языком по контенту это украина.

Язык стоит английский в системе, дело явно не в языке

Например Гугл показывает мне украинскую выдачу потому что ютуб открывается через прокси в Польше.

Может я чего-то не догоняю, но почему украинская выдача, если прокси у тебя в Польше?

Хз, но факт....

Не важно где провайдер, важно какими базами geoip пользуются остальные. Ещё можно посмотреть whois ip - чтоб определить кому принадлежит ip.
